# 3D pie using Jqplot

Tags: 3d, jqplot, pie-chart

i am changing basic 2D renderor to 3D pie renderor. Its plotting a 3D pie but all functionalities like highlight and data on slices are lost.Please help.

in library i have replaced jqplot.pieRenderer  I have replaced everyting with jqplot.pieRemdere3D  and added the below mentioned function:

```
//========My function begin@ashwni ==================

ash(rad,color,data);

//console.log("colors"+color.length);

function ash(rad,color,data){

var lastend = 0;

var data=data;
var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch

//filling the array wid global variable window.mycol
//var myColor = [window.mycol[0],window.mycol[1],window.mycol[2],window.mycol[3],window.mycol[4],window.mycol[5],window.mycol[6],window.mycol[7],window.mycol[8],window.mycol[9],window.mycol[10],window.mycol[11],window.mycol[12],window.mycol[13],window.mycol[14],window.mycol[15]];
var myColor=[];
console.log(window.mycol.length);
for(j=0;j<window.mycol.length;j++){

myColor.push(window.mycol[j]);
//console.log(myColor[j]);

} 
//console.log("data is"+color);
ctx.scale(1,0.4);

for(var e = 0; e <data.length; e++)
{


  myTotal += data[e][1];

}


for (var j=0;j<window.n;j++){

//console.log("mydatalength"+data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{  ctx.beginPath();
   if (j == 0 ||j==1||j==2) {


                            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(10,5,5,0.02)';
                            // ctx.arc(0,0,rad,0,2*Math.PI,false);
                        } else {



                            ctx.fillStyle = (myColor[i]);


                       };





 //console.log("window2"+window.mycol);

ctx.moveTo(0,j);

ctx.arc(0,j,rad,lastend,lastend+(Math.PI*2*(data[i][1]/myTotal)),false);

ctx.lineTo(0,j);

ctx.fill();


lastend += Math.PI*2*(data[i][1]/myTotal);



ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";

}
}



//====================My function end============== 

     if (fill) {
                ctx.fill();

            }
            else {
                ctx.stroke();

            }       
        }
    }
    }

    // called with scope of series
    $.jqplot.PieRenderer3D.prototype.draw = function (ctx, gd, options, plot) {
        var i;
        var opts = (options != undefined) ? options : {};
        // offset and direction of offset due to legend placement
        var offx = 0;
        var offy = 0;
        var trans = 1;
// =========Declaring mycol as a Global variable@ashwni=============        
        window.mycol =this.seriesColors;
        //console.log("window1"+window.mycol);
//===================================================================       
        var colorGenerator = new $.jqplot.ColorGenerator(this.seriesColors);
        if (options.legendInfo && options.legendInfo.placement == 'insideGrid') {
            var li = options.legendInfo;
            switch (li.location) {
                case 'nw':
                    offx = li.width + li.xoffset;
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    offx = li.width + li.xoffset;
                    break;
                case 'sw':
                    offx = li.width + li.xoffset;
                    break;
                case 'ne':
                    offx = li.width + li.xoffset;
                    trans = -1;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    offx = li.width + li.xoffset;
                    trans = -1;
                    break;
                case 'se':
                    offx = li.width + li.xoffset;
                    trans = -1;
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    offy = li.height + li.yoffset;
                    break;
                case 's':
                    offy = li.height + li.yoffset;
                    trans = -1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

      var shadow = (opts.shadow != undefined) ? opts.shadow : this.shadow;
        var fill = (opts.fill != undefined) ? opts.fill : this.fill;
        var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
        var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
        var w = cw - offx - 2 * this.padding;
        var h = ch - offy - 2 * this.padding;
        var mindim = Math.min(w,h);
        var d = mindim;

        // Fixes issue #272.  Thanks hugwijst!
        // reset slice angles array.
        this._sliceAngles = [];

        var sm = this.sliceMargin;
        if (this.fill == false) {
            sm += this.lineWidth;
        }

        var rprime;
        var maxrprime = 0;

        var ang, ang1, ang2, shadowColor;
        var sa = this.startAngle / 180 * Math.PI;

        // have to pre-draw shadows, so loop throgh here and calculate some values also.
        for (var i=0, l=gd.length; i<l; i++) {
            ang1 = (i == 0) ? sa : gd[i-1][1] + sa;
            ang2 = gd[i][1] + sa;

            this._sliceAngles.push([ang1, ang2]);

            rprime = calcRPrime(ang1, ang2, this.sliceMargin, this.fill, this.lineWidth);

            if (Math.abs(ang2-ang1) > Math.PI) {
                maxrprime = Math.max(rprime, maxrprime);  
            }
        }

        if (this.diameter != null && this.diameter > 0) {
            this._diameter = this.diameter - 2*maxrprime;
        }
        else {
            this._diameter = d - 2*maxrprime;
        }

        // Need to check for undersized pie.  This can happen if
        // plot area too small and legend is too big.
        if (this._diameter < 6) {
            $.jqplot.log('Diameter of pie too small, not rendering.');
            return;
        }

        var r = this._radius = this._diameter/2;

        this._center = [(cw - trans * offx)/2 + trans * offx + maxrprime * Math.cos(sa), (ch - trans*offy)/2 + trans * offy + maxrprime * Math.sin(sa)];

       if (this.shadow) {
            for (var i=0, l=gd.length; i<l; i++) {
                shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+this.shadowAlpha+')';

                this.renderer.drawSlice.call (this, ctx, this._sliceAngles[i][0], this._sliceAngles[i][1], shadowColor, true);
            }
        }

        for (var i=0; i<gd.length; i++) {

            this.renderer.drawSlice.call (this, ctx, this._sliceAngles[i][0], this._sliceAngles[i][1], colorGenerator.next(), false);

            if (this.showDataLabels && gd[i][2]*100 >= this.dataLabelThreshold) {
                var fstr, avgang = (this._sliceAngles[i][0] + this._sliceAngles[i][1])/2, label;

                if (this.dataLabels == 'label') {
                    fstr = this.dataLabelFormatString || '%s';
                    label = $.jqplot.sprintf(fstr, gd[i][0]);
                }
                else if (this.dataLabels == 'value') {
                    fstr = this.dataLabelFormatString || '%d';
                    label = $.jqplot.sprintf(fstr, this.data[i][1]);
                }
                else if (this.dataLabels == 'percent') {
                    fstr = this.dataLabelFormatString || '%d%%';
                    label = $.jqplot.sprintf(fstr, gd[i][2]*100);
                }
                else if (this.dataLabels.constructor == Array) {
                    fstr = this.dataLabelFormatString || '%s';
                    label = $.jqplot.sprintf(fstr, this.dataLabels[i]);

                }

                var fact = (this._radius ) * this.dataLabelPositionFactor + this.sliceMargin + this.dataLabelNudge;

                var x = this._center[0] + Math.cos(avgang) * fact + this.canvas._offsets.left;
                var y = this._center[1] + Math.sin(avgang) * fact + this.canvas._offsets.top;

                var labelelem = $('<div class="jqplot-pie-series jqplot-data-label" style="position:absolute;">' + label + '</div>').
                insertBefore(plot.eventCanvas._elem);

                if (this.dataLabelCenterOn) {
                    x -= labelelem.width() / 2;
                    y -= labelelem.height() / 2;

                }
                else {
                    x -= labelelem.width() * Math.sin(avgang / 2);
                    y -= labelelem.height() / 2;
                }
                x = Math.round(x);
                y = Math.round(y);
                labelelem.css({left:x ,top:y});
            }
        }            
    };

    $.jqplot.PieAxisRenderer3D = function() {
        $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer.call(this);
    };

    $.jqplot.PieAxisRenderer3D.prototype = new $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer();
    $.jqplot.PieAxisRenderer3D.prototype.constructor = $.jqplot.PieAxisRenderer3D;


    // There are no traditional axes on a pie chart.  We just need to provide
    // dummy objects with properties so the plot will render.
    // called with scope of axis object.
    $.jqplot.PieAxisRenderer3D.prototype.init = function(options){
        //
        this.tickRenderer = $.jqplot.PieTickRenderer;
        $.extend(true, this, options);
        // I don't think I'm going to need _dataBounds here.
        // have to go Axis scaling in a way to fit chart onto plot area
        // and provide u2p and p2u functionality for mouse cursor, etc.
        // for convienence set _dataBounds to 0 and 100 and
        // set min/max to 0 and 100.
        this._dataBounds = {min:0, max:100};
        this.min = 0;
        this.max = 100;
        this.showTicks = false;
        this.ticks = [];
        this.showMark = false;
        this.show = false; 
    };




    $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer3D = function(){
        $.jqplot.TableLegendRenderer.call(this);
    };

    $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer3D.prototype = new $.jqplot.TableLegendRenderer();
    $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer3D.prototype.constructor = $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer3D;

    /**
     * Class: $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer
     * Legend Renderer specific to pie plots.  Set by default
     * when user creates a pie plot.
     */
    $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer3D.prototype.init = function(options) {
        // Group: Properties
        //
        // prop: numberRows
        // Maximum number of rows in the legend.  0 or null for unlimited.
        this.numberRows = null;
        // prop: numberColumns
        // Maximum number of columns in the legend.  0 or null for unlimited.
        this.numberColumns = null;
        $.extend(true, this, options);
    };

    // called with context of legend
    $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer3D.prototype.draw = function() {
        var legend = this;
        if (this.show) {
            var series = this._series;


            this._elem = $(document.createElement('table'));
            this._elem.addClass('jqplot-table-legend');

            var ss = {position:'absolute'};
            if (this.background) {
                ss['background'] = this.background;
            }
            if (this.border) {
                ss['border'] = this.border;
            }
            if (this.fontSize) {
                ss['fontSize'] = this.fontSize;
            }
            if (this.fontFamily) {
                ss['fontFamily'] = this.fontFamily;
            }
            if (this.textColor) {
                ss['textColor'] = this.textColor;
            }
            if (this.marginTop != null) {
                ss['marginTop'] = this.marginTop;
            }
            if (this.marginBottom != null) {
                ss['marginBottom'] = this.marginBottom;
            }
            if (this.marginLeft != null) {
                ss['marginLeft'] = this.marginLeft;
            }
            if (this.marginRight != null) {
                ss['marginRight'] = this.marginRight;
            }

            this._elem.css(ss);

            // Pie charts legends don't go by number of series, but by number of data points
            // in the series.  Refactor things here for that.

            var pad = false, 
                reverse = false,
                nr, 
                nc;
            var s = series[0];

            var colorGenerator = new $.jqplot.ColorGenerator(s.seriesColors);

            if (s.show) {
                var pd = s.data;
                if (this.numberRows) {
                    nr = this.numberRows;
                    if (!this.numberColumns){
                        nc = Math.ceil(pd.length/nr);
                    }
                    else{
                        nc = this.numberColumns;
                    }
                }
                else if (this.numberColumns) {
                    nc = this.numberColumns;
                    nr = Math.ceil(pd.length/this.numberColumns);
                }
                else {
                    nr = pd.length;
                    nc = 1;
                }

                var i, j;
                var tr, td1, td2; 
                var lt, rs, color;
                var idx = 0; 
                var div0, div1;   

                for (i=0; i<nr; i++) {
                    tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
                    tr.addClass('jqplot-table-legend');

                    if (reverse){
                        tr.prependTo(this._elem);
                    }

                    else{
                        tr.appendTo(this._elem);
                    }

                    for (j=0; j<nc; j++) {
                        if (idx < pd.length){
                            lt = this.labels[idx] || pd[idx][0].toString();
                            color = colorGenerator.next();
                            if (!reverse){
                                if (i>0){
                                    pad = true;
                                }
                                else{
                                    pad = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                if (i == nr -1){
                                    pad = false;
                                }
                                else{
                                    pad = true;
                                }
                            }
                            rs = (pad) ? this.rowSpacing : '0';


                            td1 = $(document.createElement('td'));
                            td1.addClass('jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-swatch');
                            td1.css({textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: rs});

                            div0 = $(document.createElement('div'));
                            div0.addClass('jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline');
                            div1 = $(document.createElement('div'));
                            div1.addClass('jqplot-table-legend-swatch');
                            div1.css({backgroundColor: color, borderColor: color});
                            td1.append(div0.append(div1));

                            td2 = $(document.createElement('td'));
                            td2.addClass('jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-label');
                            td2.css('paddingTop', rs);

                            if (this.escapeHtml){
                                td2.text(lt);
                            }
                            else {
                                td2.html(lt);
                            }
                            if (reverse) {
                                td2.prependTo(tr);
                                td1.prependTo(tr);
                            }
                            else {
                                td1.appendTo(tr);
                                td2.appendTo(tr);
                            }
                            pad = true;
                        }
                        idx++;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        return this._elem;                
    };

    $.jqplot.PieRenderer3D.prototype.handleMove = function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
        if (neighbor) {
            var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
            plot.target.trigger('jqplotDataMouseOver', ins);
            if (plot.series[ins[0]].highlightMouseOver && !(ins[0] == plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightedSeriesIndex && ins[1] == plot.series[ins[0]]._highlightedPoint)) {
                plot.target.trigger('jqplotDataHighlight', ins);
                highlight (plot, ins[0], ins[1]);
            }
        }
        else if (neighbor == null) {
            unhighlight (plot);
        }
    };


    // this.eventCanvas._elem.bind($.jqplot.eventListenerHooks[i][0], {plot:this}, $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks[i][1]);

    // setup default renderers for axes and legend so user doesn't have to
    // called with scope of plot
    function preInit(target, data, options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.axesDefaults = options.axesDefaults || {};
        options.legend = options.legend || {};
        options.seriesDefaults = options.seriesDefaults || {};
        // only set these if there is a pie series
        var setopts = false;
        if (options.seriesDefaults.renderer == $.jqplot.PieRenderer3D) {
            setopts = true;
        }
        else if (options.series) {
            for (var i=0; i < options.series.length; i++) {
                if (options.series[i].renderer == $.jqplot.PieRenderer3D) {
                    setopts = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (setopts) {
            options.axesDefaults.renderer = $.jqplot.PieAxisRenderer3D;
            options.legend.renderer = $.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer3D;
            options.legend.preDraw = true;
            options.seriesDefaults.pointLabels = {show: false};
        }
    }

    function postInit(target, data, options) {
        for (var i=0; i<this.series.length; i++) {
            if (this.series[i].renderer.constructor == $.jqplot.PieRenderer3D) {
                // don't allow mouseover and mousedown at same time.
                if (this.series[i].highlightMouseOver) {
                    this.series[i].highlightMouseDown = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // called with scope of plot
    function postParseOptions(options) {
        for (var i=0; i<this.series.length; i++) {
            this.series[i].seriesColors = this.seriesColors;

            this.series[i].colorGenerator = $.jqplot.colorGenerator;
        }
    }

    function highlight (plot, sidx, pidx) {
        var s = plot.series[sidx];
        var canvas = plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas;
        canvas._ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas._ctx.canvas.width, canvas._ctx.canvas.height);
        s._highlightedPoint = pidx;
        plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightedSeriesIndex = sidx;

        s.renderer.drawSlice.call(data,s, canvas._ctx, s._sliceAngles[pidx][0], s._sliceAngles[pidx][1], s.highlightColorGenerator.get(pidx), false);
    }

    function unhighlight (plot) {
        var canvas = plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas;
        canvas._ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas._ctx.canvas.width, canvas._ctx.canvas.height);
        for (var i=0; i<plot.series.length; i++) {
            plot.series[i]._highlightedPoint = null;
        }
        plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightedSeriesIndex = null;
        plot.target.trigger('jqplotDataUnhighlight');
    }

    function handleMove(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
        if (neighbor) {
            var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
            var evt1 = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataMouseOver');
            evt1.pageX = ev.pageX;
            evt1.pageY = ev.pageY;
            plot.target.trigger(evt1, ins);
            if (plot.series[ins[0]].highlightMouseOver && !(ins[0] == plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightedSeriesIndex && ins[1] == plot.series[ins[0]]._highlightedPoint)) {
                var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataHighlight');
        evt.which = ev.which;
                evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
                evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
                plot.target.trigger(evt, ins);
                highlight (plot, ins[0], ins[1]);
            }
        }
        else if (neighbor == null) {
            unhighlight (plot);
        }
    } 

    function handleMouseDown(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
        if (neighbor) {
            var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
            if (plot.series[ins[0]].highlightMouseDown && !(ins[0] == plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightedSeriesIndex && ins[1] == plot.series[ins[0]]._highlightedPoint)) {
                var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataHighlight');
        evt.which = ev.which;
                evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
                evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
                plot.target.trigger(evt, ins);
                highlight (plot, ins[0], ins[1]);
            }
        }
        else if (neighbor == null) {
            unhighlight (plot);
        }
    }

    function handleMouseUp(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
        var idx = plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightedSeriesIndex;
        if (idx != null && plot.series[idx].highlightMouseDown) {
            unhighlight(plot);
        }
    }

    function handleClick(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
        if (neighbor) {
            var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
            var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataClick');
        evt.which = ev.which;
            evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
            evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
            plot.target.trigger(evt, ins);
        }
    }

    function handleRightClick(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
        if (neighbor) {
            var ins = [neighbor.seriesIndex, neighbor.pointIndex, neighbor.data];
            var idx = plot.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightedSeriesIndex;
            if (idx != null && plot.series[idx].highlightMouseDown) {
                unhighlight(plot);
            }
            var evt = jQuery.Event('jqplotDataRightClick');
        evt.which = ev.which;
            evt.pageX = ev.pageX;
            evt.pageY = ev.pageY;
            plot.target.trigger(evt, ins);
        }
    }    

    // called within context of plot
    // create a canvas which we can draw on.
    // insert it before the eventCanvas, so eventCanvas will still capture events.
    function postPlotDraw() {
        // Memory Leaks patch    
        if (this.plugins.PieRenderer3D && this.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas) {
            this.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas.resetCanvas();
            this.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas = null;
        }

        this.plugins.PieRenderer3D = {highlightedSeriesIndex:null};
        this.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas = new $.jqplot.GenericCanvas();

        // do we have any data labels?  if so, put highlight canvas before those
        var labels = $(this.targetId+' .jqplot-data-label');

        if (labels.length) {
            $(labels[0]).before(this.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas.createElement(this._gridPadding, 'jqplot-PieRenderer3D-highlight-canvas', this._plotDimensions, this));
        }
        // else put highlight canvas before event canvas.
        else {
            this.eventCanvas._elem.before(this.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas.createElement(this._gridPadding, 'jqplot-PieRenderer3D-highlight-canvas', this._plotDimensions, this));
        }

        var hctx = this.plugins.PieRenderer3D.highlightCanvas.setContext();
        this.eventCanvas._elem.bind('mouseleave', {plot:this}, function (ev) { unhighlight(ev.data.plot); });
    }

    $.jqplot.preInitHooks.push(preInit);

    $.jqplot.PieTickRenderer3D = function() {
        $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer3D.call(this);
    };

    $.jqplot.PieTickRenderer3D.prototype = new $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer();
    $.jqplot.PieTickRenderer3D.prototype.constructor = $.jqplot.PieTickRenderer;

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: just as a side note: pie charts are usually considered harmful in visualization, and their 3D counterparts even worst. In fact, 3d pie charts should really be avoided....! For 2D pie charts: this is due to the fact humans have very poor area and angle perception (compared to position, for example). For the 3D: the perspective is distorting things even more, and nothing meaningful can be perceived at the end. Just use a plain old 2D bar chart!

Comment: (you can check this out! : http://eagerpies.com/close-the-bars-down/ )

Comment: Thanks WhitAngl ,but I need this 3D pie in some of my works.  :(